# print out arrays of strings in label (visual studio wpf, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

how do I make wpf label print out arrays of strings by using only one label text. I try to loop the answer by putting foreach. however it only print the last string of the array.

this is the example:

```
input : h t t p

string word = input_box.Text;
string[] split = word.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' });
foreach (string s in split)
{
     if (s.Trim() != " ")
        label1.Content = s;
}
```

output:

```
p
```

can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 4):

use `label1.Content += s;`
instead of `label1.Content = s;`

but better would be using a StringBuilder

```
string word = input_box.Text;
string[] split = word.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' });
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string s in split)
{
     if (s.Trim() != " ")
         sb.Append(s);
}

label1.Content = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: `String.Join(String.Empty, word.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }).Where(s => s.Trim() != String.Empty))` ?

Comment: hi jens, thanks for the tip and also the additional tip to shortened the code. Actually I wanted to print out the output into arrays like this h t t p